# How can I use CC41-A HM10 BLE as a master to detect a Android Mobile or iPhone as slave?

Tags: android, iphone, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, hm-10

I’m trying to use the **CC41a BLE** as a master to detect a Android Mobile(Redmi Prime,Motorola moto x play)

but when I do AT+INQ it only returns :
“+INQS
+INQE
Devices Found 0”

In the same time these two mobile phones working as a master detect CC41a as a slave with the help of HM BLE Terminal App.

Do I needed to use any APP to make mobile as slave which can be detected by the CC41a master?
Does anybody have already succeed using AT+INQ command on those CC41A?

To which all mobile phones does CC41a will act as a master?

Comment: Same problem here, is not detecting any device. I saw AT+POWE was to 0, anyway i increased it and the same... Did you solved it? Thanks.

Comment: Me too. Did anyone stumble on a solution?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this website](https://www.hackster.io/achindra/bluetooth-le-using-cc-41a-hm-10-clone-d8708e) it's likely we have a knock off Chinese board that only connects to other CC41a devices in slave mode. The solution appears to be to buy a better board!

Signs of a knock off board include:

- It's missing a crystal in the top left corner (placing the Bluetooth antenna on top facing you)
  See http://wiki.makespacemadrid.org/images/7/72/HM-10-fake.jpg
- It needs CR+LF terminated commands to reply. Original HM-10 will reply to any un-terminated AT commands
- Doesn't support usual commands like AT+ADTY3  or AT+DELO2 needed for best performance as a beacon.
- When you issue an unsupported command you don't get any reply at all in a clone
- First commands you try, like AT+VERR? or AT+VERS? following usual guides don't return anything.
- AT+VERSION returns this firmware: +VERSION=Firmware V3.0.6,Bluetooth V4.0 LE